# Directionality in "object model" vs "database model"

Tags: database-design, object-model

1. Is it correct to say that whenever we talk about directionality (unidirectional or bidirectional), we usually refer to object model? (I haven't seen people using it when designing a database)
2. Does directionality have to be the same in both "object model" and "database model"? Consider an example with Employee and Department entities:

   - For "database model", I want to specify that this is a unidirectional relationship where many employees are in the same Department; whereas I don't need to specify which employees a Department has.
   - For "object model", I want to specify that this is a bidirectional relationship where an Employee object will have a Department object, and a Department object will have a collection of Employee objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that whenever we talk about directionality (unidirectional or bidirectional), we usually refer to object model? (I haven't seen people using it when designing a database)

When people talk about one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, they are implicitly referring to the (uni)directionality of a relation from one table 'A' to another 'B'. There can be cases of referencing the 'B' records back into 'A' (as a separate field) - making it bi-directional. These cases usually involve non-simple delete/update queries since referential integrity checks may cause issues.

> Does directionality have to be the same in both "object model" and "database model"?

By design maybe, usually not in practice. Taking your example and my stmt above: To maintain a list of which Departments have which Employees, you could create a 3rd table for the sake of query performance - and of course, update that table when there's a change in the Emps or Depts. This would maintain the reverse relationships from B to A. That would make it similar to the object model since you would compute which Depts have which Emps anyway, and **store** that back in the Depts objects.

Alternatively, in your object model (to keep it aligned with your DB model), what you could have done is: every time you want to show which Depts have which Employees, you could iterate over your Emp objects and get their _dept properties to **compute** it each time. That would be like the A to B db model without the 3rd table.

Whether or not you have issues with pointer allocation / obj references in the reverse reference obj model depends on the specifics of the programming language you're using and whether or not you do the clean-up of deleted/updated Emps in the Dept objects as well. In C++, you can manage the pointers yourself and not have issues. Not sure what some higher-level languages would permit.
(Note to self: would their garbage collection cause problems?)